# sending email with arabic content through java i

Tags: java, email, arabic

I want to send email with Arabic content through java mail ,
but every Arabic word in the message appears like ????????????? ,
how can i make the encoding to utf_8 in order to support Arabic language ???
since i use that code

```
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
    message.setSubject(subject_a);
    message.setText(messageDetails_a);
    Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Something fell on your `?` key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add some charset-information to the methods. If subject or message-body does contain other than US-ASCII characters, the default charset will be used for encoding. Explicitly setting the charset to UTF-8 will always be safe:

```
String charset="UTF-8";
message.setSubject(subject_a,charset);
message.setText(messageDetails_a,charset);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a MimeMessage (and keep it as a MimeMessage) and use the `setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");` method for the subject.

`setContent( messageContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8" );` will handle UTF-8 in the content.

With pure text :

```
setText(messageContent, "UTF-8");
```

---

**Resources :**

- [UTF-8 subjects in javax.mail](http://www.isocra.com/2006/11/utf-8-subjects-in-javaxmail/)

Comment: This will send a HTML-Email, but @Alaa wants to send a text message,

Comment: Well, almost the same thing with `setText()`